# How to handle empty String in csv file in Super CSV java?

Tags: java, string, csv, null, supercsv

I am using Super CSV to read csv files. One of my csv file look like below:

```
smth
"abc"
""
```

As You can see in the third row the String is empty. I have got a class which is responsible for analyze this file. A piece is shown below:

```
final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] {    
    new NotNull()//what I need to declare here
};
```

Now I have got "new NotNull()", but this is not good for my case, bacause I can have empty String. What I need to declare there? I tried to use this: "StrMinMax(0, 10)", but I get a message that String is null. How can I solve it, what I need to declare? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Super CSV documentation](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/cell_processors.html) shows you can simply use the [Optional](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/cellprocessor/Optional.html) cell processor. i.e.

```
final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] {    
    new Optional()
};
```

You could just use `null`, but `Optional` is more meaningful, and allows you to chain further processors after it.